# Column operation within function turns data frame into empty or unexpected value

Tags: r

I have a function that was working well, I wanted to clean up the output by removing one of the columns and turning the NA values in another column to 1 with these commands:

```
  df$PlateIden <- NULL

  df$PlateNum[is.na(df$PlateNum)] <- 1
```

These work when I use them outside my function directly on the dataframe, but when I use them within the function my dataframe turns into a value that is either "empty" or "1" if either function is used.

Here is my whole function:

```
cleanup_safe <- function(df,addproject,adduser){

  colnames(df) <- "FileName"

  df$RunDate <- str_match(df$FileName, "^[a-zA-Z ]*(\\d+)")[,2]

  df$RunDate <- ymd(df$RunDate)

  df$PlateNum <- str_match(df$FileName, "(?<=Plate|plate)[_ ]?(\\d)")[,2]

  df$PlateIden <- str_match(df$FileName, "(?<=Plate|plate)[_ ]?\\d*[_ ]?([a-zA-Z])")[,2]

  df$User <- "adduser"

  df$Project <- "addproject"

  df <- df[!duplicated(df[,c("User","Project","RunDate","PlateNum")]),]

  df <- within(df, ID <- cumsum(!duplicated(df[c("User","Project","RunDate")])))

  df$PlateIden <- NULL

  df$PlateNum[is.na(df$PlateNum)] <- 1

}
```

Here is a test dataset

```
test <- c("20160801, Optimization, gp70_B.CaseA_V1_V2 Coupling Testing, Plate 1a, IgG-Biot, MAF.srbx",
                      "20160801, Optimization, gp70_B.CaseA_V1_V2 Coupling Testing, Plate 1a, IgG-Biot, SAF.srbx",
                      "20160801, Optimization, gp70_B.CaseA_V1_V2 Coupling Testing, Plate 1a, IgG-Biot.srbx",
                      "20160801, Optimization, gp70_B.CaseA_V1_V2 Coupling Testing, Plate 1b, IgG-Biot, MAF.srbx",
                      "20160801, Optimization, gp70_B.CaseA_V1_V2 Coupling Testing, Plate 1b, IgG-Biot, SAF.srbx",
                      "20160801, Optimization, gp70_B.CaseA_V1_V2 Coupling Testing, Plate 1b, IgG-Biot.srbx",
                      "20160801, Optimization, gp70_B.CaseA_V1_V2 Coupling Testing, Plate 2, IgG-Biot, MAF.srbx",
                      "20160801, Optimization, gp70_B.CaseA_V1_V2 Coupling Testing, Plate 2, IgG-Biot, SAF.srbx",
                      "20160801, Optimization, gp70_B.CaseA_V1_V2 Coupling Testing, Plate 2, IgG-Biot.srbx",
                      "20160802, Optimization, New lot of gp70_B.CaseA_V1_V2 Testing, Plate 1a, IgG-Biot, MAF.srbx",
                      "20160802, Optimization, New lot of gp70_B.CaseA_V1_V2 Testing, Plate 1a, IgG-Biot.srbx",
                      "20160802, Optimization, New lot of gp70_B.CaseA_V1_V2 Testing, Plate 1b, IgG-Biot, MAF.srbx",
                      "20160802, Optimization, New lot of gp70_B.CaseA_V1_V2 Testing, Plate 1b, IgG-Biot, SAF.srbx",
                      "20160802, Optimization, New lot of gp70_B.CaseA_V1_V2 Testing, Plate 1b, IgG-Biot.srbx",
                      "20160802, Optimization, New lot of gp70_B.CaseA_V1_V2 Testing, Plate 2a, IgG-Biot, MAF.srbx",
                      "20160802, Optimization, New lot of gp70_B.CaseA_V1_V2 Testing, Plate 2a, IgG-Biot, SAF.srbx",
                      "20160802, Optimization, New lot of gp70_B.CaseA_V1_V2 Testing, Plate 2a, IgG-Biot.srbx",
                      "20160802, Optimization, New lot of gp70_B.CaseA_V1_V2 Testing, Plate 2b, IgG-Biot, MAF.srbx",
                      "20160802, Optimization, New lot of gp70_B.CaseA_V1_V2 Testing, Plate 2b, IgG-Biot, SAF.srbx",
                      "20160802, Optimization, New lot of gp70_B.CaseA_V1_V2 Testing, Plate 2b, IgG-Biot.srbx",
                      "20160802, Optimization, New lot of gp70_B.CaseA_V1_V2 Testing, Plate 3a, IgG-Biot, MAF.srbx",
                      "20160802, Optimization, New lot of gp70_B.CaseA_V1_V2 Testing, Plate 3a, IgG-Biot, SAF.srbx",
                      "20160802, Optimization, New lot of gp70_B.CaseA_V1_V2 Testing, Plate 3a, IgG-Biot.srbx",
                      "20160802, Optimization, New lot of gp70_B.CaseA_V1_V2 Testing, Plate 3b, IgG-Biot, MAF.srbx",
                      "20160802, Optimization, New lot of gp70_B.CaseA_V1_V2 Testing, Plate 3b, IgG-Biot, SAF.srbx",
                      "20160802, Optimization, New lot of gp70_B.CaseA_V1_V2 Testing, Plate 3b, IgG-Biot.srbx",
                      "20160802, Optimization, New lot of gp70_B.CaseA_V1_V2 Testing, Plate 4a, IgG-Biot, MAF.srbx",
                      "20160802, Optimization, New lot of gp70_B.CaseA_V1_V2 Testing, Plate 4a, IgG-Biot, SAF.srbx",
                      "20160802, Optimization, New lot of gp70_B.CaseA_V1_V2 Testing, Plate 4a, IgG-Biot.srbx",
                      "20160802, Optimization, New lot of gp70_B.CaseA_V1_V2 Testing, Plate 4b, IgG-Biot, MAF.srbx",
                      "20160802, Optimization, New lot of gp70_B.CaseA_V1_V2 Testing, Plate 4b, IgG-Biot, SAF.srbx",
                      "20160802, Optimization, New lot of gp70_B.CaseA_V1_V2 Testing, Plate 4b, IgG-Biot.srbx",
                      "20160812, Optimization, Testing New lot of NGS, Plate 1, IgG-Biot, MAF.srbx",
                      "20160812, Optimization, Testing New lot of NGS, Plate 1, IgG-Biot, SAF.srbx",
                      "20160812, Optimization, Testing New lot of NGS, Plate 1, IgG-Biot.srbx",
                      "20160812, Optimization, Testing New lot of NGS, Plate 2, IgG-Biot, MAF.srbx",
                      "20160812, Optimization, Testing New lot of NGS, Plate 2, IgG-Biot, SAF.srbx",
                      "20160812, Optimization, Testing New lot of NGS, Plate 2, IgG-Biot.srbx",
                      "20160812_a, Optimization, Testing New lot of NGS, Plate 1, IgG-Biot, MAF.srbx",
                      "20160812_a, Optimization, Testing New lot of NGS, Plate 1, IgG-Biot, SAF.srbx",
                      "20160812_a, Optimization, Testing New lot of NGS, Plate 1, IgG-Biot.srbx",
                      "20160812_a, Optimization, Testing New lot of NGS, Plate 2, IgG-Biot, MAF.srbx",
                      "20160812_a, Optimization, Testing New lot of NGS, Plate 2, IgG-Biot, SAF.srbx",
                      "20160812_a, Optimization, Testing New lot of NGS, Plate 2, IgG-Biot.srbx")

dataframe <- as.data.frame(test)

dataframe <- cleanup_safe(dataframe,testproject,testuser)
```

Comment: Can you share the data with us?

Comment: Added test data set

Comment: Your test data is a `data.frame` with one single column? Is that correct? Best to use `dput` if you want to share sample data.

Comment: @AwesomeeExpress you can use `df <- df[, !(names(df) %in% "PlateIden"), drop = F]` instead of `df$PlateIden <- NULL`. For the other line , I don't know why it's behaving like that. Will it be fine for you to get a solution using some package?

Comment: @Maurits Evers - Yep, that's a clip of what my data looks like. My actual data is like 40K rows of file names read from a directory, I read it as a dataframe because then I can expand out from there. Thanks for the dput recommendation, didn't know about that.

Comment: @Suchait, Thanks! Now I just need to figure out a work around for converting NA values. Fine to use a package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `df$PlateNum[is.na(df$PlateNum)] <- 1` with

```
setDT(df)
  df[is.na(PlateNum), PlateNum := 1].
```

So, your entire would be like:

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)

test <- c("20160801, Optimization, gp70_B.CaseA_V1_V2 Coupling Testing, Plate 1a, IgG-Biot, MAF.srbx",
          "20160801, Optimization, gp70_B.CaseA_V1_V2 Coupling Testing, Plate 1a, IgG-Biot, SAF.srbx",
          "20160801, Optimization, gp70_B.CaseA_V1_V2 Coupling Testing, Plate 1a, IgG-Biot.srbx",
          "20160801, Optimization, gp70_B.CaseA_V1_V2 Coupling Testing, Plate 1b, IgG-Biot, MAF.srbx",
          "20160801, Optimization, gp70_B.CaseA_V1_V2 Coupling Testing, Plate 1b, IgG-Biot, SAF.srbx",
          "20160801, Optimization, gp70_B.CaseA_V1_V2 Coupling Testing, Plate 1b, IgG-Biot.srbx",
          "20160801, Optimization, gp70_B.CaseA_V1_V2 Coupling Testing, Plate 2, IgG-Biot, MAF.srbx",
          "20160801, Optimization, gp70_B.CaseA_V1_V2 Coupling Testing, Plate 2, IgG-Biot, SAF.srbx",
          "20160801, Optimization, gp70_B.CaseA_V1_V2 Coupling Testing, Plate 2, IgG-Biot.srbx",
          "20160802, Optimization, New lot of gp70_B.CaseA_V1_V2 Testing, Plate 1a, IgG-Biot, MAF.srbx",
          "20160802, Optimization, New lot of gp70_B.CaseA_V1_V2 Testing, Plate 1a, IgG-Biot.srbx",
          "20160802, Optimization, New lot of gp70_B.CaseA_V1_V2 Testing, Plate 1b, IgG-Biot, MAF.srbx",
          "20160802, Optimization, New lot of gp70_B.CaseA_V1_V2 Testing, Plate 1b, IgG-Biot, SAF.srbx",
          "20160802, Optimization, New lot of gp70_B.CaseA_V1_V2 Testing, Plate 1b, IgG-Biot.srbx",
          "20160802, Optimization, New lot of gp70_B.CaseA_V1_V2 Testing, Plate 2a, IgG-Biot, MAF.srbx",
          "20160802, Optimization, New lot of gp70_B.CaseA_V1_V2 Testing, Plate 2a, IgG-Biot, SAF.srbx",
          "20160802, Optimization, New lot of gp70_B.CaseA_V1_V2 Testing, Plate 2a, IgG-Biot.srbx",
          "20160802, Optimization, New lot of gp70_B.CaseA_V1_V2 Testing, Plate 2b, IgG-Biot, MAF.srbx",
          "20160802, Optimization, New lot of gp70_B.CaseA_V1_V2 Testing, Plate 2b, IgG-Biot, SAF.srbx",
          "20160802, Optimization, New lot of gp70_B.CaseA_V1_V2 Testing, Plate 2b, IgG-Biot.srbx",
          "20160802, Optimization, New lot of gp70_B.CaseA_V1_V2 Testing, Plate 3a, IgG-Biot, MAF.srbx",
          "20160802, Optimization, New lot of gp70_B.CaseA_V1_V2 Testing, Plate 3a, IgG-Biot, SAF.srbx",
          "20160802, Optimization, New lot of gp70_B.CaseA_V1_V2 Testing, Plate 3a, IgG-Biot.srbx",
          "20160802, Optimization, New lot of gp70_B.CaseA_V1_V2 Testing, Plate 3b, IgG-Biot, MAF.srbx",
          "20160802, Optimization, New lot of gp70_B.CaseA_V1_V2 Testing, Plate 3b, IgG-Biot, SAF.srbx",
          "20160802, Optimization, New lot of gp70_B.CaseA_V1_V2 Testing, Plate 3b, IgG-Biot.srbx",
          "20160802, Optimization, New lot of gp70_B.CaseA_V1_V2 Testing, Plate 4a, IgG-Biot, MAF.srbx",
          "20160802, Optimization, New lot of gp70_B.CaseA_V1_V2 Testing, Plate 4a, IgG-Biot, SAF.srbx",
          "20160802, Optimization, New lot of gp70_B.CaseA_V1_V2 Testing, Plate 4a, IgG-Biot.srbx",
          "20160802, Optimization, New lot of gp70_B.CaseA_V1_V2 Testing, Plate 4b, IgG-Biot, MAF.srbx",
          "20160802, Optimization, New lot of gp70_B.CaseA_V1_V2 Testing, Plate 4b, IgG-Biot, SAF.srbx",
          "20160802, Optimization, New lot of gp70_B.CaseA_V1_V2 Testing, Plate 4b, IgG-Biot.srbx",
          "20160812, Optimization, Testing New lot of NGS, Plate 1, IgG-Biot, MAF.srbx",
          "20160812, Optimization, Testing New lot of NGS, Plate 1, IgG-Biot, SAF.srbx",
          "20160812, Optimization, Testing New lot of NGS, Plate 1, IgG-Biot.srbx",
          "20160812, Optimization, Testing New lot of NGS, Plate 2, IgG-Biot, MAF.srbx",
          "20160812, Optimization, Testing New lot of NGS, Plate 2, IgG-Biot, SAF.srbx",
          "20160812, Optimization, Testing New lot of NGS, Plate 2, IgG-Biot.srbx",
          "20160812_a, Optimization, Testing New lot of NGS, Plate 1, IgG-Biot, MAF.srbx",
          "20160812_a, Optimization, Testing New lot of NGS, Plate 1, IgG-Biot, SAF.srbx",
          "20160812_a, Optimization, Testing New lot of NGS, Plate 1, IgG-Biot.srbx",
          "20160812_a, Optimization, Testing New lot of NGS, Plate 2, IgG-Biot, MAF.srbx",
          "20160812_a, Optimization, Testing New lot of NGS, Plate 2, IgG-Biot, SAF.srbx",
          "20160812_a, Optimization, Testing New lot of NGS, Plate 2, IgG-Biot.srbx")

dataframe <- as.data.frame(test)


  cleanup_safe <- function(df,addproject,adduser){

  colnames(df) <- "FileName"

  df$RunDate <- str_match(df$FileName, "^[a-zA-Z ]*(\\d+)")[,2]

  df$RunDate <- ymd(df$RunDate)

  df$PlateNum <- str_match(df$FileName, "(?<=Plate|plate)[_ ]?(\\d)")[,2]

  df$PlateIden <- str_match(df$FileName, "(?<=Plate|plate)[_ ]?\\d*[_ ]?([a-zA-Z])")[,2]

  df$User <- "adduser"

  df$Project <- "addproject"

  df <- df[!duplicated(df[,c("User","Project","RunDate","PlateNum")]),]

  df <- within(df, ID <- cumsum(!duplicated(df[c("User","Project","RunDate")])))

  df <- df[, !(names(df) %in% "PlateIden"), drop = F]

  setDT(df)
  df[is.na(PlateNum), PlateNum := 1]



}

dataframe <- cleanup_safe(dataframe,testproject,testuser)
```

This will give you an output:-

```
    FileName    RunDate PlateNum    User    Project ID
1:   20160801, Optimization, gp70_B.CaseA_V1_V2 Coupling Testing, Plate 1a, IgG-Biot, MAF.srbx 2016-08-01        1 adduser addproject  1
2:    20160801, Optimization, gp70_B.CaseA_V1_V2 Coupling Testing, Plate 2, IgG-Biot, MAF.srbx 2016-08-01        2 adduser addproject  1
3: 20160802, Optimization, New lot of gp70_B.CaseA_V1_V2 Testing, Plate 1a, IgG-Biot, MAF.srbx 2016-08-02        1 adduser addproject  2
4: 20160802, Optimization, New lot of gp70_B.CaseA_V1_V2 Testing, Plate 2a, IgG-Biot, MAF.srbx 2016-08-02        2 adduser addproject  2
5: 20160802, Optimization, New lot of gp70_B.CaseA_V1_V2 Testing, Plate 3a, IgG-Biot, MAF.srbx 2016-08-02        3 adduser addproject  2
6: 20160802, Optimization, New lot of gp70_B.CaseA_V1_V2 Testing, Plate 4a, IgG-Biot, MAF.srbx 2016-08-02        4 adduser addproject  2
7:                 20160812, Optimization, Testing New lot of NGS, Plate 1, IgG-Biot, MAF.srbx 2016-08-12        1 adduser addproject  3
8:                 20160812, Optimization, Testing New lot of NGS, Plate 2, IgG-Biot, MAF.srbx 2016-08-12        2 adduser addproject  3
```

Comment: Thanks Suchait! Wish I understood while the original wasn't working but oh well.

Comment: You're welcome. Thanks for pointing this out. Because it was weird. I don't know why the last line of code was not working from inside the function.